# Rotating contents of div wont come smooth in all browsers using transform property

Tags: css, transform

I am using `transform` CSS  property to rotate text but the seems to come differently in different browser, I tried it with different fonts it doesn't come smooth.

is their a way i can make it smooth. link for [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92f8M.jpg)

jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/RmYyR/1/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

a nice trick to get rid of those jagged edges on CSS transformations in Chrome is to add the CSS property -webkit-backface-visibility with a value of hidden. that's all i got for you. makes it a bit smoother.